# Initiate TextToSpeech from non Activity class?

Tags: java, android, text-to-speech

I build a helper class with a couple of methods I need for text to speech synthesis however I cannot manage to initiate a TextToSpeech object without getApplicationContext(). How do I initiate it?

```
public class SpeechHelper {
    private TextToSpeech speech;
    private Context context = null;

    public SpeechHelper(Context context)
    {
        this.context = context;
        speech = new TextToSpeech(getApplicationContext(), context);
    }
```

Comment: The first argument should be your activity's (or service) context.  The second is the listener object for initialization callback.

Comment: should I pass it from my activity to the constructor?

Comment: You should follow scott's answer but make your class abstract with an abstract method onFinishInitialize which you would call in onInit(). In the SpeechHelper, you should take care of all the errors that are sensible for this class to handle. For example, when you call setLanguage and the error is LANG_MISSING_DATA, this class should start an activity to go to Google play store to install data. When you extends this SpeechHelper class you can implements onUtteranceCompleted or UtteranceProgressListener.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's your code with the interface implemented:

```
public class SpeechHelper implements OnInitListener {
    private TextToSpeech speech;
    private Context context = null;

    public SpeechHelper(Context context)
    {
        this.context = context;
        speech = new TextToSpeech(context, this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onInit(int status) {
        // TextToSpeech engine is initialized
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot! do you know if I could speak("something") from a static function? I believe not but I'm not sure

Comment: You could call speak() from a static function, but it'd still need to call through an instance of your SpeechHelper class. That would present its own set of challenges.